# Convert JSON array of objects into nasted json tree usning JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, treeview

I have a API which return JSON array of objects. Which need to be converted into nested JSON array in a parent/child relation based on "parientid" in each node. Where "parientid" is null it will be root nodes and other will be child node of there parent node. Below is the sample JSON array which I get from API.

```
  var API_DATA = [
  {
    "DIAGID": 1,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Certain infectious or parasitic diseases ",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Chapter",
    "PARENTID": null,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 2,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Gastroenteritis or colitis of infectious origin  ",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Section",
    "PARENTID": 1,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 3,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Bacterial intestinal infections",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Category",
    "PARENTID": 2,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 4,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Cholera",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Group",
    "PARENTID": 3,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 5,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Intestinal infection due to other Vibrio",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Disease",
    "PARENTID": 4,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 6,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Intestinal infections due to Shigella",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Disease",
    "PARENTID": 4,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 7,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Intestinal infections due to Escherichia coli",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Disease",
    "PARENTID": 4,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 8,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Neoplasms",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Chapter",
    "PARENTID": null,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 9,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Neoplasms of brain or central nervous system",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Section",
    "PARENTID": 8,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 10,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Primary neoplasms of brain ",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Category",
    "PARENTID": 9,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 11,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Gliomas of brain",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Group",
    "PARENTID": 10,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 12,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Glioblastoma of brain",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Disease",
    "PARENTID": 11,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 13,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Other specified gliomas of brain",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Disease",
    "PARENTID": 11,
  }
]
```

I want to convert it into tree format in parent/child relation based on "ParentId" in each object. Below is the example of JSON in which I want to convert it. I want "DIAGID" as value and "DIAGNOSIS" as name.

```
const data = {
  label: 'search me',
  value: 'searchme',
  children: [
    {
      label: 'search me too',
      value: 'searchmetoo',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'No one can get me',
          value: 'anonymous',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

I am new to javascript I have used javascript array, map function but need little guide on what approach should i follow.

Comment: how do you plan on handling circular references? or should they just be ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a standard approach for trees with a single loop.

```js
var data = [{ DIAGID: 1, DIAGNOSIS: "Certain infectious or parasitic diseases ", DIAGTYPE: "Chapter", PARENTID: null }, { DIAGID: 2, DIAGNOSIS: "Gastroenteritis or colitis of infectious origin  ", DIAGTYPE: "Section", PARENTID: 1 }, { DIAGID: 3, DIAGNOSIS: "Bacterial intestinal infections", DIAGTYPE: "Category", PARENTID: 2 }, { DIAGID: 4, DIAGNOSIS: "Cholera", DIAGTYPE: "Group", PARENTID: 3 }, { DIAGID: 5, DIAGNOSIS: "Intestinal infection due to other Vibrio", DIAGTYPE: "Disease", PARENTID: 4 }, { DIAGID: 6, DIAGNOSIS: "Intestinal infections due to Shigella", DIAGTYPE: "Disease", PARENTID: 4 }, { DIAGID: 7, DIAGNOSIS: "Intestinal infections due to Escherichia coli", DIAGTYPE: "Disease", PARENTID: 4 }, { DIAGID: 8, DIAGNOSIS: "Neoplasms", DIAGTYPE: "Chapter", PARENTID: null }, { DIAGID: 9, DIAGNOSIS: "Neoplasms of brain or central nervous system", DIAGTYPE: "Section", PARENTID: 8 }, { DIAGID: 10, DIAGNOSIS: "Primary neoplasms of brain ", DIAGTYPE: "Category", PARENTID: 9 }, { DIAGID: 11, DIAGNOSIS: "Gliomas of brain", DIAGTYPE: "Group", PARENTID: 10 }, { DIAGID: 12, DIAGNOSIS: "Glioblastoma of brain", DIAGTYPE: "Disease", PARENTID: 11 }, { DIAGID: 13, DIAGNOSIS: "Other specified gliomas of brain", DIAGTYPE: "Disease", PARENTID: 11 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(({ DIAGID, DIAGNOSIS, PARENTID }) => {
            Object.assign(t[DIAGID] = t[DIAGID] || {}, { label: DIAGID, name: DIAGNOSIS });
            t[PARENTID] = t[PARENTID] || {};
            t[PARENTID].children = t[PARENTID].children || [];
            t[PARENTID].children.push(t[DIAGID]);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(data, null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer I will try you suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) when you want to turn an `Array` into another shape (in this case an `Array` of a different length, containing trees).

In the code example below I first use `reduce` to turn the existing array into a tree-shape with `children`, and then I use a `map` on the resulting array, that uses a recursive function that walks the tree and gives each object it's final shape.

Also notice that the [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method is used to return a new `Array` with the value added at the end.

```js
function findParent(arr, diagId) {
  return arr.find((parent) => parent.DIAGID === diagId);
}

function createTreeNode(value) {
  return {
    label: value.DIAGNOSIS,
    value: value.DIAGID,
    children: (value.children !== undefined)
      ? value.children.map(createTreeNode)
      : undefined
  };
}

function createTree(data) {
  return data
    // first restructure existing nodes as a tree
    .reduce((result, value, index, originalArray) => {
      if (value.PARENTID !== null) {
        const parent = findParent(originalArray, value.PARENTID);

        if (parent) {
          // add as child if has parent
          parent.children = (parent.children || []).concat(value);
        }

        return result;
      } else {
        // Add value to top level of the result array
        return result.concat(value);
      }
    }, [] /* Initialize with empty result array */)
    // them map to new data type
    .map(createTreeNode);
}

var API_DATA = [
  {
    "DIAGID": 1,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Certain infectious or parasitic diseases ",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Chapter",
    "PARENTID": null,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 2,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Gastroenteritis or colitis of infectious origin  ",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Section",
    "PARENTID": 1,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 3,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Bacterial intestinal infections",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Category",
    "PARENTID": 2,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 4,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Cholera",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Group",
    "PARENTID": 3,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 5,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Intestinal infection due to other Vibrio",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Disease",
    "PARENTID": 4,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 6,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Intestinal infections due to Shigella",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Disease",
    "PARENTID": 4,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 7,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Intestinal infections due to Escherichia coli",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Disease",
    "PARENTID": 4,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 8,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Neoplasms",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Chapter",
    "PARENTID": null,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 9,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Neoplasms of brain or central nervous system",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Section",
    "PARENTID": 8,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 10,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Primary neoplasms of brain ",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Category",
    "PARENTID": 9,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 11,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Gliomas of brain",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Group",
    "PARENTID": 10,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 12,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Glioblastoma of brain",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Disease",
    "PARENTID": 11,
  },
  {
    "DIAGID": 13,
    "DIAGNOSIS": "Other specified gliomas of brain",
    "DIAGTYPE": "Disease",
    "PARENTID": 11,
  }
];

const tree = createTree(API_DATA);

console.log(tree);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer... your solution looks good. Let me try it